# ERROR 000539: Error running expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-parser, expression, error-000539

I am trying to calculate my End_Streets field within two joined tables. I want to remove the redundant SECONDARYN value from the STREETS field.

```
" & ".join(!IntersectAndEnds2.Streets!.split(" & ").remove(!StreetSplit2.SECONDARYN!))
```

Here is a portion of my table:

[image: Joined Table]

Here is the error I am receiving when I run the expression in the field calculator.

[image]

Error typed out:

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: " & ".join(u"ACORN CT & LARAN RD".split(" & ").remove(u"ACORN CT"))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line1, in  TypeError Failed to execute (CalculateField)

Comment: To confirm, you're wanting to remove the value in SECONDARYN from STREETS?  So `ACORN CT & LARAN RD` becomes `LARAN RD`?

Comment: Are you trying to modify field in a joined table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to join a List.remove (returned from .split()), but a List.remove doesn't return anything, so you'd have to remove the item from the list and then join, or if you want to do it inline, I think this would work to exclude what you don't want:

```
" & ".join(i for i in !IntersectAndEnds2.Streets!.split(" & ") if i <> !StreetSplit2.SECONDARYN!)
```

Comment: And actually my answer doesn't quite work because arcmap thinks the != is a field rather than "not equal".

Comment: change it to `<>`

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't know that Python accepted that.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/comparisons.html - `<>` is obsolescent however in this case it works as the `!` is signifying something else to arcgis

Comment: I have been struggling with this for two days because I'm not a python person. This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to remove the "ACORN CT & " from "ACORN CT & LARAN RD", leaving just "LARAN RD".

Try this expression

```
!STREETS!.replace("{} & ".format( !SECONDARYN! ), '').replace(" & {}".format( !SECONDARYN! ), '')
```

which will leave just "LARAN RD".

I am concerned that you are trying to update a joined table.  Your table in the screenshot is called `StreetSplit2` but in your expression it looks like the `Streets` field is in another table called `IntersectAndEnds2`.  You can't update a joined table using the field calculator, you'd need to calculate that field in the actual table (and if necessary perform the join in the other direction).

Comment: I don't think this would not for the case where the SECONDARYN field value is the last road in the list.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst nice spot, have updated around that.

Comment: It also would not work for the case where there is no cross street and only the road itself is listed, which can occur for her data since it includes cul-de-sac, stub and dead end points.